# VB6 - compile error with do while loop syntax

Tags: loops, vb6, do-while

I have a do-while loop that's supposed to do three things, go through a text file line by line, the text file contains pathnames and filenames (C:\Folder\file1.txt).

If the line contains a certain string, it then copies a file to that location, renames it to what it is named in the text file, and then replaces a string within the copied file.
If not, it goes on to the next line.

I thought this would be fairly straight forward but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm currently unable to even compile as I'm getting errors saying the loop's syntax is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated, here's the entire function's code:

```vb
Private Sub Command2_Click()

    Dim LineData As String 
    Dim FileHandle As Integer

    FileHandle = FreeFile
    Open "C:\textfile.txt" For Input As #FileHandle

    Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
        Line Input #FileHandle, LineData
        If InStr(LineData, ".log") Then
            FileCopy "C:\thefile.log",LineData
            Open LineData For Input As #3
             #3 = Replace$(#3, "abc", "xyz")
        Else
        End If  
    Loop
    
    Close #FileHandle
    Close #3

    MsgBox "Copy, Replace, Complete!"

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by this statement -  #3 = Replace$(#3, "abc", "xyz")
?

Comment: I suggest using scripting runtime library (scrrun.dll) which has simpler syntax to deal with file and directory read/write operations.

Comment: You should consult http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/default.aspx for help with vb6 - click on the library tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe

```
#3 = Replace$(#3, "abc", "xyz")
```

is valid.
You will need to read the contents of that file in, preferable line by line (or some sensible chunk at a time), do your replacement, then write it back out to a new file.  As you are copying the file anyway I would suggest reading it from the source location, and writing the new version to the location that the file would have been copied to anyway.

for example...

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
 Dim LineData As String
 Dim FileHandle As Integer
 Dim sourceHandle as Integer
 Dim destHandle as Integer
 dim temp as string
 FileHandle = FreeFile
 Open "C:\textfile.txt" For Input As #FileHandle
 Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
  Line Input #FileHandle, LineData
  If InStr(LineData, ".log") Then
   sourceHandle=FreeFile
   Open "C:\thefile.log" For Input as #sourceHandle
   destHandle=FreeFile
   Open LineData For Output as #destHandle
   Do while Not EOF(sourceHandle)
    Line Input #sourceHandle,temp
    temp=replace$(temp,"abc","xyz")
    Print #destHandle,temp
   Loop
   Close #destHandle
   Close #sourceHandle
  End If
 Loop
Close #FileHandle
MsgBox "Copy, Replace, Complete!"
End Sub
```

Sorry if there are any errors, this isn't tested as I don't have a VB IDE installed on this computer.

Comment: Actually all looks perfect except for 
      Do while Not EOF(#sourceHandle)
    LineInput #sourceHandle,temp
Are showing as a syntax error Don't have MSDN installed though :/

Comment: I think you just need to get rid of all the "#" above.  I'm pretty sure the # is just if you're using a literal number ("#3" for example) but not if you're using a variable as above.

Comment: It should be "Close destHandle" not "Close #destHandle", for example.

Comment: The LineInput should be Line Input - I'm sure thats just a typo by pipTheGeek.  Why do I get the impression that JAckie-Brown just copied this code from somewhere?
MSDN seems to say that the '#' is optional - just as I remember it to be.

Comment: Yeah that was the case with the seperation, but the # is necessary so not sure where you're looking.  This is actually something I hacked together from several old projects and was on my way out so just posted the lines that came up in error

Comment: don't ya just love the consistant syntax of VB6. Line Input and Print the # is required. Close and Open it is optional and EOF it must not be used!

Answer (score 1):

#3 = Replace$... is your problem line... fixing that and other stuff results in this:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim LineData As String
  Dim FileHandle As Integer
  Dim Buffer As String
  FileHandle = FreeFile
  Open "C:\thefile.log" For Binary Access Read As #FileHandle
  Buffer = Space(LOF(FileHandle))
  Get #FileHandle, , Buffer
  Buffer = Replace(Buffer, "abc", "xyz")
  Close #FileHandle
  FileHandle = FreeFile
  Open "C:\textfile.txt" For Input As #FileHandle
  Do Until EOF(FileHandle)
    Line Input #FileHandle, LineData
    If InStr(LineData, ".log") Then
      Open LineData For Output As #3
      Print #3, Buffer;
      Close #3
    End If
  Loop
  Close #FileHandle
  MsgBox "Copy, Replace, Complete!"
End Sub
```

If you prefer minimalism and short code you could go with this instead:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
  ''// This code requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting runtime (Project -> References)
  Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim Files() As String
  Dim File As String
  Dim Data As String
  Data = Replace(FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\thefile.log").ReadAll(), "abc", "xyz")
  Files = Split(FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\textfile.txt").ReadAll(), vbCrLf)
  For Each File In Files
    If InStr(File, ".log") > 0 Then FSO.CreateTextFile(File, True).Write Data
  Next
  MsgBox "Copy, Replace, Complete!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you're opening filehandle, then #3, but you close them in the same order, and you should be closing #3, then filehandle.

What I see happening is that filehandle is opened, then it searches for a line that contains ".log", then it does something - so far, so good. However, it then opens #3, does something else, and then loops. It needs to close #3 when it's done with it.

Moving "Close #3" up 4 lines (to the next statement after the "#3 = Replace..." should do what you expect and should compile okay.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a different approach to you. I've done something like this except I knew before hand I was making a copy, and my method was to open the source and a new target (copy). I then read the source file line by line make the needed changes to the variable I read the line into before writing it back out to the copy. My files were never more than a couple of k and this was plenty quick enough and eliminates one of your loops. You would have to have a variable inside your loop to tell you what to rename the file to once done, or delete the file if you did not find the line you were looking for and do not need the copy.